# Azure Devops, pipeline with powershell that filters those files that have been made last commit

Tags: azure-devops

I would need to know how to configure a pipeline that copies only those files from a static website that have had the last commit

I currently have the yaml configured as follows

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
- powershell: |
       Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) -Recurse |  Where { $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false } | ? { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).addminutes(-5) } |
        Foreach-Object {
          Write-Host $_.FullName  $_.LastWriteTime
        }   
  displayName: 'OBTENER DIFERENCIAS GIT'
This powershell returns all the files from the remote repository when what I want is for it to return the files that have undergone a change in the last 5 minutes or those files that are in the last commit
```

Comment: This powershell returns all the files from the remote repository when what I want is for it to return the files that have undergone a change in the last 5 minutes or those files that are in the last commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to configure a pipeline that copies only those files from a static website that have had the last commit

You can use git command to get the changed files of last commit.

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(Build.SourceVersion)
```

Here is the Pipeline sample:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 2
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(Build.SourceVersion))
      echo $files
      $temp=$files -split ' '
      $count=$temp.Length
      echo "Total changed $count files"
```

**Note:** The default value of fetchDepth is 1.  We need to set the fetchDepth to 2 to compare the current commit and previous commit to get the changed files.

**Result：**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer it has been helpful, now what I am trying is to add the files with commit to Related-artifacts but I am not getting it, I have modified your script as follows

Comment: ForEach($f in $temp){
         echo "---------------------"         
         $targetFile = "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\$f";         
         echo "$f > $targetFile"
         New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;
         Copy-Item $f -destination $targetFile;         
         Write-Host "---------------------"
      }

Comment: I am doing something wrong since the files are not added to the artifact, any solution?
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer it has been helpful, now what I am trying is to add the files with commit to Related-artifacts but I am not getting it, I have modified your script as follows
$files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(Build.SourceVersion))
echo $files
$temp=$files -split ' '
ForEach($f in $temp){
echo "---------------------"
$targetFile = "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)$f";
echo "$f > $targetFile"
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;
Copy-Item $f -destination $targetFile;
Write-Host "---------------------"
}
Write-Host "------Nº FICHERO MODIFICADOS-----"
$count=$temp.Length
echo "Total changed $count files"
Write-Host "---------------------------------"
I am doing something wrong since the files are not added to the artifact, any solution?
Thanks for your attention